# ¿Como puedo implementar un operador en una clase en java?

Tags: java

Quiero implementar el operador `<=` en una clase de java, pero no se como realizar dicha implementación.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que quieres hacer es **sobrecargar** un operador.

Y, a diferencia de en `C++`, en `Java` no se puede hacer.

Puedes crear un método (p. ej "*menorOIgual*".) aunque los más estándar (porque te puede servir en muchas otras situaciones) es hacer que tu clase implemente `java.lang.Comparable`. Implementando *compare* como toca, tienes que `a <= b` de escribe como `a.compare(b) <= 0`.